# how to set header title as non scrollable for a detail page in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

i have a view where i have list, now i required a  header sub-title for view, which should not get scroll.

If i place a panel inside view it's start scrolling...i need a stickey one. Need help.

```
 config: {
        AccountName: '',
        AccountNumber: '',
        style: 'background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(223,223,223) 60%, rgb(199,199,199) 80%);',
        layout: 'vbox',
        height: '100%',
        scrollable: true,

 items: [ .....

        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set the doc property of an item.

For example a docked toolbar component.

```
items:[
    {
      xtype: 'toolbar',
      docked: 'top'
    }
 ]
```

The docked property will not be part of the parents (your list) scrollable component.

Comment: i have already a titlebar coming from navigation view. inside the content i required a list for that a header text which should not scroll.

ok i solved it by creating 2 views, which contains only inside header ttile and called list as xtype.

thanks!!